# How to refresh mat-table after add data to datasource?

Tags: angular

I am using a mat-table to list the content  task . I can also add new comment using dialog panel. After I added a comment and returned back I want my datasource to refresh to show the changes they made.

```
private update(value: any, id: string): void {
this.dataService.updateCommentaire(id,value)


.subscribe(
    data => {


   this.dataService
  .getTachesByDossierAndSite(this.idDossier, this.idSite)
  .subscribe(
  data => {
    this.taches = data;
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.taches);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  });
        this.successMessage = "La mise à jour a été effectuée avec succès.";
        this._success.subscribe((message) => this.successMessage = message);
        debounceTime.call(this._success, 5000).subscribe(() => this.successMessage = null);
    }
  );
```

}

So I have tried to call a refresh method where I get the task from the backend again and then I reinitialize the data source :( any help please to refresh mat-table after add data to datasource!!

Comment: what happened when you tried to reinitialize the datasource? any exception?provide more info

Comment: i want to refresh mat-table after add data to datasource without get the task from backend again and reinitialize the data source

Comment: I do not understand your requirements? you want to refresh the table without making an `HTTP` call to backend ?

Comment: could you provide a stackblitz of what have you done so far?

Comment: yes i want to refresh the table without making call to backend

Answer (score 2):

You can update your global datasource replacing the data setting with the new data variable.

For example your global variable:

```
public dataSource: MatTableDataSource<any[]> = new MatTableDataSource([]);
```

To update its data you just replace data variable:

```
const data = [...this.dataSource.data];

this.dataService
      .getTachesByDossierAndSite(this.idDossier, this.idSite)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.taches = data;
          this.dataSource.dataSource.data = data;
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to refresh data without reloading the whole `HTML` page is reassigning the data source in one of Angular's lifecycle hooks. In the below code snippet, to display upto date data I'm using the `AfterViewChecked` hook.

`component.ts`

```
ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
  this.lstorage = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('employee')!);
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.lstorage);
  this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```